# Inheritance: Is there a way to discover the class a method was called from?

Tags: java, inheritance, this

With this code:

```
class SuperTest {
    SuperTest() { whoAmI(); }
    void whoAmI() { System.out.println(getClass().getName()); }
}

class Test extends SuperTest {
    Test() { whoAmI(); }        
}
```

`new Test()` will print `"Test"` twice. As a beginner I was expecting the output to be `"SuperTest / Test"`. I understand now why this is not possible, and why the implicit `this` will refer to child type only.

However I can't find what `whoAmI()` should be to actually print the output `SuperTest / Test`.
Said otherwise: how can `whoAmI()` access the name of the type it is "called from"?

EDIT: I'm changing the title of the question for a new one which describes the problem better.
(old was: Inheritance: Is there a "this-equivalent" construct to refer to super type from derived type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, because in both cases `getType()` is called on the same object of type `Test`. This is because JVM knows the type of the object being created is of the derived class `Test` at the time the base constructor is called, so that is the type being printed.

This behavior is not universal to all programming languages, but it works this way in Java.

If a class wants to access its own `Class` object, it can do so *statically*, i.e. using the `SuperTest.class` expression.

To get the behavior that you want you can pass the class to `whoAmI` from the constructor, like this:

```
class SuperTest {
    SuperTest() { whoAmI(SuperTest.class); }
    void whoAmI(Class c) { System.out.println(c.getName()); }
}
class Test extends SuperTest {
    Test() { whoAmI(Test.class); }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean there is no dynamic way to know the type where a method is defined? We must always provide a static value?

Comment: @mins You can find the class in which the method is defined using reflection APIs, but usually providing a static type is easier.

Comment: Oops, I meant "the class from which the method is called". But I'm afraid the answer will still be valid.

Comment: @mins You are correct, there is no way to tell from what class a method is called, unless the caller tells the method.

Comment: @mins, There _is_ a way for a method to get the name of its caller at run-time:  Create a new Throwable, call it's fillInStackTrace() method, call its getStackTrace() method, and look at the first StackTraceElement in the array.  Bad news is, you can get the _name_ of the calling method, but not the signature, and you can get the _name_ of the caller's class, but not the package; so not enough information to unambiguously ID the caller, but maybe enough info for debugging/logging purposes.

Comment: Clever! thanks. It's worth updating your answer with this alternative, depending on the context, one or the other may be more appropriate. I like the second one.

Comment: @mins Getting the caller through `fillInStackTrace()` borders on a hack, and it is also grossly inefficient. It should never be used for purposes other than debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For your amusement, here is a test program demonstrating a "whoAmI" that will print to any required depth of ancestry:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sub2 sub2 = new Sub2();
    System.out.println("Four levels");
    sub2.whoAmi(4);
    System.out.println("Two levels");
    sub2.whoAmi(2);
  }
  public void whoAmi(int levels){
    if(levels > 1){
      Class<? extends Object> ancestor = getClass();
      for(int i=1; i<levels && ancestor != null; i++){
        ancestor = ancestor.getSuperclass();
      }
      if(ancestor != null){
        System.out.println(ancestor.getName());
      }
      whoAmi(levels - 1);
    } else {
      System.out.println(getClass().getName());      
    }
  }
}

class Sub1 extends Test {
}

class Sub2 extends Sub1 {
}
```

Comment: It prints the desired number of ancestors of the object, and for n=1 it is the same than the code in the question, right? Anyway interesting!

Comment: @mins Correct. It is essentially the combination of the original code and the getSuperclass() idea for finding an ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

> how can `whoAmI()` access the name of the type it is "called from"?

You can access the superclass using [`Class.getSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--):

```
void whoAmI() {
    Class superclass = getClass().getSuperclass();
    String superclassText = "no superclass found";
    if (superclass != null) superclassText = superclass.getName();
    System.out.println(superclassText);
}
```

This technically answers your question, but only because I have assumed that the method we are discussing belongs to the superclass (which it does in your example).

But perhaps you really want to know the answer to ***"How can a method identify which class it is defined in even if it is invoked on an instance of a subclass?"*** This would be a much more complicated matter. While [`java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaringClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass--) seems to do what you ask, you first need the declaring class' `Class` instance (i.e., `SuperTest.class`) which defeats the point—if you had that, you wouldn't need to use java.lang.reflect.Method at all.

However, if I can change the premise a little bit more, let's assume you embed *every* class with a static Class instance like this:

```
private final static Class THIS_CLASS = SuperTest.class;
```

Then it becomes possible to write a *method* which doesn't access its declaring class by name, because it can assume that whichever class it gets copy-pasted to will have `THIS_CLASS` defined:

```
void whoAmI() {
    final String myName = "whoAmI";
    final Class[] myParamTypes = {};
    String result;
    try {
        Method thisMethod = THIS_CLASS.getDeclaredMethod(myName, myParamTypes);
        result = "I am " + thisMethod.getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." +
                myName + Arrays.toString(myParamTypes);
        // Now swap the square brackets from Arrays.toString for parentheses
        result = result.replaceAll("\\[", "\\(").replaceAll("\\]", "\\)");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
        result = ex.toString();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This will yield `I am packagename.MinsSuperTest.whoAmI()` as output.

Comment: Thanks. The first version of whoAmI will print `"SuperTest / SuperTest"`, which is not the expected output. The second version does indeed answer another problem (knowing where the method is defined, but not from where it is called.)